# Swift: Array Size with UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to figure out how the array works with Swift.  I understand that you use `let` to create an immutable array and `var` to create a mutable array.  Yet, Swift's array is not quite the same as Objective's `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.  I get that.

In the example that follows, I create a mutable array with one element.  Actually, I want to start with no element.  But if I do, I won't be able to add a new string to it.  If I start with one element, then I won't be able to add a new string to it after the original element is removed.  So what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
    var myArray:[String] = ["GGG"] // or var myArray:[String] = []

    @IBAction func add1Tapped(sender:AnyObject) {
        let index = tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let selectedRow = index()?.row
        if selectedRow < 0 {
            return
        } else {
            let txt = nameField1.text
            myArray.append(txt)
            tableView1.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return myArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:textCellIdentifier)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel!.text = myArray[row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I want to start with no element. But if I do, I won't be able to add a new string to it.*". Why?

Comment: You can add an element to your `array` anytime as follows.  `myArray.append("your string")`

Comment: Also what dies it have to do with UITableview ?

Comment: @Eendje That's because the application has no string to start with in its array when it starts up.  The table is empty.

Comment: @Pyro Obviously, the table refers to myArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all your needs should work as expected:

```
// create an empty array of strings
var myArray: [String] = []

// add two elements
myArray.append("the first element")
myArray.append("the second element")

// remove both elements
myArray.removeAll()

// add another element
myArray.append("the third but now first element")

myArray.count
```

[image: screenshot from playground]

**EDIT**

try and change your add method like this:

```
@IBAction func add1Tapped(sender:AnyObject) {
    if let _ = tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow, txt = nameField1.text {
        print("will append \(txt) to myArray")
        myArray.append(txt)
        tableView1.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope.  I've already said "if I do, I won't be able to add a new string to it."

Comment: It's pretty much the same as your "myArray.append("the first element")" with IBAction.

Comment: but something has to be different. :) cause in my case it works. so if you need some help you have to show some code i guess...

Comment: take a look at the bottom of my post, change your code and see if the print statement gets executed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108030/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-el-tomato).